# Redirect user to previous link after login

Tags: php

Question is quite simple. I have a PHP website and whenever a user comes in through a link that requires login, I want user to be redirected to login page and then, after he finish login, I want him to be redirected to link he tried to access when he came into the website.

And that's it...

Comment: Where exactly is your problem then?

Comment: pass the requested url as a session var or hidden post var or store it in a cookie, then use `Location`

Comment: Either save the current URL into the session (problematic with multiple tabs open), or pass it as a parameter to the login script.

Comment: @Prinzhorn - It's not actually a "problem" since I was looking for suggestions and best practices to implement it. And it's actually quite forward: URL1 is locked to registered users only, user is redirected to Login URL, after login, user is sent back to URL1...

Comment: @JoeT - Thank you for your answer. Maybe the cookie solution is a nice one. But what if user has cookies dissabled?

Comment: @CBroe - What do you mean with "pass it as a parameter to the login script"?

Comment: @putvande - Same answer to you as I gave Prinzhorn.

Comment: Pedro in the case where you are relying on cookies or javascript, you would run a test from PHP and if those are not enabled you display a message "you must have cookies / javascript enabled to use this feature"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the url you want to return to. Look at stackoverflow for example. Here is the URL I visited

[Redirect user to previous link after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342617/redirect-user-to-previous-link-after-login)

I click "log in" and I'm sent to

https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f25342617%2fredirect-user-to-previous-link-after-login

If they want to send me back after I log in, then can do

```
$returnurl = make_everything_safe($_GET['returnurl']);
header("Location: $returnurl")
```

Comment: My favorite answer. Simple and functional! :D It's working. Thank you dude.

Comment: Sorry, what is **make_everything_safe** feature in PHP? I couldn't find it in google.

Comment: It's not a real function. Just a placeholder to remind people to check their GET data before using it.

Comment: Here I was looking all over for a function called make_everything_safe()...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to store the current page url in your cookies, and then when the user is logged you test if the cookie exists, if it exists then you redirect to the url in this cookie

```
// Set your cookie before redirecting to the login page
$current_page = 'http://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$_COOKIE['redirect_to'] = $current_page;
```

After the user is logged

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['redirect_to']))
{
   $url = $_COOKIE['redirect_to'];
   unset($_COOKIE['redirect_to']);
   header('location:' . $url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers you have been given will work just fine, but here is a slightly more in depth answer that uses very simple PHP. No setting cookies or session variables which I would consider extra steps; you have to make sure to start your session on the next page for example.

What I would do is have a script run that catches the page they tried to access. You would have to place this on every page that a visitor could land on, and then make sure to pass this value on. Here is a great example:

```
// Function to get the full URL even on SSL connections 
function curPageURL() {
   $pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
   $pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
   return $pageURL; // Here the full URL is returned
}
```

This code is from [Web Cheat Sheet](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php) which has more scripts that you may want to use. Some are even shorter than this one.

Next is to keep passing this value on. Simple urlencode the returned value (so its safe) and do this:

```
// This sends them to your login script and 
// adds the page they were heading to in the url to access with $_GET[];
header ("Location: $yourLoginPageUrl?sendBackTo=$returnedPageUrl");
```

Now you can do two things. The less safe is to not doing anything, let them login and on the login script simple access the value with $_GET['sendBackTo']; Because the URL had the value in it when they submitted the form it should still be there to access since its the reffering page. NOT RECOMMENDED though. The smart thing is to use a hidden text field on the login form and just echo the URL into so you know its there. Then after a successful login send them to it.

You still will need to handle catching log ins with no recorded URL to go back to.